# Is there a way to interact with uTorrent remotely?

Tags: java, android, remote-access, bittorrent, utorrent

Im working on an Android project that makes the users add torrent downloads to their uTorrent client (or other) remotely from tehir Android device.

I've had a look to the webUI API of uTorrent but this requires the users to specify their hostname or IP address and make a port redirection in their router.

I've seen that uTorrent provides a remote access on https://remote.utorrent.com that dosent require any of these operations (but activating the option in uTorrent settings)... but I can't find any API access related to this.

Has anyone know about any way to remotely add torrents to uTorrent or any other desktop bittorrent client remotely? It doesen't matter if I have to get a working server between the Android device and the bittorrent client (in PHP, JS, Java...)

Thank you by advance.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.utorrent.web ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm looking for a solution to use from java code in Android app developement